# Referencing dataframe index when checking for duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for duplicate entries in a dataframe column. When I find a duplicate entry, I want to raise an error message and point to the index. However, I also have many missing entries in the column, which are not considered duplicates.

My code right now looks like:

```
 temp = df[pd.notnull(df['col1'])
 dups = temp.duplicated('col1') 
 for x in dups: 
      if x == True: 
            # Print error message which points to the index of x
```

I tried adding in a row counter, but the pd.notnull messes up the count as it does not consider duplicates. Is there another way of finding duplicates?

Thanks

Comment: Honestly, I would prefer it if you could provide some sample input and expected output. That way we can reduce the back and forth business.